# APEX. What item should use for HTML?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I'm working with oracle apex.

I want to use an item to render arbitrary html, and update it with dynamic actions.

But there is no "HTML" item, so what is the Item that I should use for that purpose?

There is a "legacy, hidden" item type named "HTML expression", but it says that is deprecated and "unsupported", so there must be a new type of item for that purpose, I guess.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1VEuV.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I often use an item; or you can create a static HTML region and update its contents using javascript. It depends on your purpose.

```
$("#regionid > div.uRegionContent").html("new content goes here");
```

(Note: the div class may differ depending on what region template you select).

Answer (score 1):

I found that I should use a "Display only" item, with "Escape special characters" disabled.

It should be updated with a "Set value" dynamic action with also "Escape special characters" disabled.